# Show element on higher number

Tags: javascript, css, ajax

I have a script that gets a number from my database and what I want with this is the higher number it is, the more elements to show.

Let's take a look at the code:

```
 setInterval(function player(){
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "url",
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                var number = parsed_data.number;
                    if(number >= 100) {
                      $('#element1').css('display','block'); 
                    }
                   if(number >= 1000) {
                       $('#element2').css('display','block');
                    }
            }
    });
    },1000);
```

Okey, so this works the first step I want it to. But I also want to remove it again, because now if I raises the number to 100 it shows element1 (super), but if I then take the number down again under 100 it will still show.

And my .css

```
#element1, #element2 { display: none; }
```

So what am I missing here? I have also tried with .setAttribute

Thanks in advance

Comment: After your if's, why not add some else-statements? **else if(number < 100) { $(#element").hide(); }** ?

Comment: Couldn't you just add 

if(number<100) //display: none

?

Comment: If you open your console, I'll bet good money you get a "parse error", as the dataType is set to "json", and you're parsing an actual javascript object as a json string

Comment: This is why it is so great to ask all of you guys, you guys think when I don't sometimes. Well, can´t see anything wrong in my console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
setInterval(function player(){
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST", 
            url: "url",
            datatype: 'json',
            success: function(data){
                var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
                var number = parsed_data.number;
                if(number >= 100) {
                    $('#element1').css('display','block'); 
                } else if(number < 100) {
                    $('#element1').hide();
                }
                if(number >= 1000) {
                    $('#element2').css('display','block');
                } else if(number < 1000) {
                    $('#element2').hide();
                }
            }
        });
    },
1000);
```

Only thing is.. I think it needs to be **if(number >= 1000 && number >= 100) {** - Not sure though.

Comment: Thanks @Snorlax, just what I didn't think off and why I needed you! Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

Dont u need a if statsment ?

```
if(number <= 99) {
  $('#element').css('display','block'); 
}
```

or

```
else {
  $('#element').css('display','block'); 
}
```

And then a

```
#element { display: none; }
```

Answer (score 0):

When the `dataType` is set to `json`, it's parsed automagically by jQuery, parsing the data once more creates a parse error :

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "url",
        datatype: 'json'
    }).done(function (data) {
        var number = parseInt(data.number, 10);
        $('#element1').toggle(number >= 100);
        $('#element2').toggle(number >= 1000);
    });
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should hide all elements and show them again according to the number returned by your AJAX request.

```
success: function(data) {
  var parsed_data = $.parseJSON(data);
  var number = parsed_data.number;
  // hide all elements
  $("[id^='element']").hide();
  // show them again according to `number`
  if (number >= 100)  $('#element1').show();
  if (number >= 1000) $('#element2').show();
}
```